# Azure AD B2C using custom policy login journey MFA

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication, azure-policy

In my project there is a login flow using Azure B2C (custom policy) where customer provide his email/pwd or Id/pwd and B2C checks it and validate which is working fine now.

we would like to customize it further by enabling MFA in the same login journey where user will get one activate code to email (TOTP) after TOTP validate along with credentials then authentication flow should be done.

However,

1. if user is opt for "Remember me for 30 days" (during TOTP provided) then B2C should by pass this MFA from 2nd login onwards till 30 days time period
2. If there are any unusual and suspicious behaviour then B2C should detects and enable MFA automatically regardless of above "Remember me" case.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of risk behaviours and MFA, your best option is to enable [conditional access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/conditional-access-user-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow).

Comment: Best to explain an actual answer, vs posting just a link (link-only answers aren't valid answers)